# Error while checking specific value at index is null

Tags: java, arraylist

I have below list defined,

```
List<BigDecimal> empList = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
```

And as per below code if condition throws error ***The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List***

```
for(int i1=0;i1<12;i1++) { 
  if(empList[i1]==null){ 
    empList[i1]= new BigDecimal("0.00");
  }
}
```

The same code works well in Groovy but does not work in Java.

Comment: Can you accept one of the below answers or explain why those answers doesn't work? @Wit Wikky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a syntax error . In java list are accessed as

```
empList.get(i1)
```

and

```
empList.set(i1,new BigDecimal("0.00"))
```

or you are free to use array instead of List but in this case you will have to define the array length which stays fixed.

```
BigDecimal[] empList = new BigDecimal[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be :

```
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 12; i1++) {
        if (empList.get(i1) == null) {
            empList.set(i1, new BigDecimal("0.00"));
        }
    }
```

A list collection needs has its own methods. Use those.